# How do you calculate the expected return of a casino bonus?

Tags: statistics, expected-value

There's a casino offer where you get a free £50 bonus when you create an account, but the bonus has to be wagered 40x (you have to play £2000 of games on the casino) before the bonus can be withdrawn to your bank account.

My maths question is: how do I calculate the average expected return of this bonus?

What I mean by that, in case it doesn't make any sense, is if I wager through £2000, I could still have £40 of the bonus left afterwards, so the expected value in this case would be £40, but if I lost all of the bonus before I finished the £2000 wagering, then the return would be £0. So how do I calculate an average return from the bonus?

Please assume that the entire £2000 wagering is completed on the same game so the variance of the game and the 'return to player' will stay the same throughout. I'm guessing the three factors that will effect the average return are: variance of the game, 'return to player', and the bet size (e.g £5 spins on a slot would have a different average return on the bonus than £1 spins on the same slot).

Is there an equation that will calculate the average expected return of this bonus?

**Edit**
I've just had a thought, would the fact that once you lose the £50 bonus you can't keep wagering effect the calculation as well? Because there's a limit to how far below the starting point you can go, but there isn't a limit to how much above the starting point it can go.

**2nd Edit**
Here are some results I got online from an Expected Value Simulator. For a £50 bonus that has to wagered 40x (£2000 total) on a game with an RTP of 99%, I got the following results when I changed the only thinged I changed was the variance of the game. Here are the results...[image: EV simulator results]

All 3 casino sites I've tested this on, give similar results, but I can't understand why the EV isn't just £40? I would link the sites, but you have to have a paid membership. Is there any logic behind there calculations? is bust rate effecting how they calculate their answer?

Comment: The possibility of going bankrupt can only make the expectation worse.  The calculation will assume you can wager 2000 and get the 50 paid back.  If you go broke before wagering 2000, you don't get the 50 and are worse off.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on the game. Generally you’ll get
$$\mathbb E(40X+50)=40\mathbb EX + 50$$
If we for example take a game with two options such as roulette with colors. Then we have a probability for winning of in this case $18/37$, and you basically win or loose your bet. So the expected value
$$\mathbb EX = B\cdot18/37-B\cdot 19/37) = -B/37 $$
So with $B=50$ we get
$$ \mathbb E(40X) = -40B/37 = -2000/37$$

So then
$$ \mathbb E(40X+50) = 50-2000/37=-150/37$$
Thus at least in this case you will not expect to make a positive even with the bonus.

Comment: Do you know how the spin size would effect this though?

Comment: The spin size does not matter for the expected value.  Whether you bet 1 unit 2000 times or 2000 units 1 time, your expected return is the same.  The first option will have lower variance, but the expectation is the same.  A better approach is to look for a game where the house edge is smaller.  The basic pass line on craps is a house edge of about $0.5\%$, so wagering $2000$ only loses $10$ and the $50$ you get back puts you ahead.  All the other bets at the craps table are worse.

Comment: @willmahoney If I understand you correctly you ask for the effect of doing a different number of spins with a diffterent bet that still amounts to 2000 total.

That of course depends on the kind of game. All of this is assuming that each spin is independent. Now if the win/loss is proportional to the bet you have for games $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and bets $b_1,\ldots,b_n$ something like
$$\mathbb E(\sum b_iX_i) = \mathbb E(X_1)\sum b_i$$
So in such a case the expected value only depends on the total sum of bets.

Comment: Now, if the win/loss is *not* proportional to the bet, this could be quite different, but usually that is not the case. Also if the spins are not independent this is not true, as you’d be able to adjust bets according to previous information.

Comment: I've edited my question to show results that I'm getting from EV simulators online, I don't understand if they're making up their answers? One site says you need to use the formula "EV = Bonus - (Average Wagering * House Edge)", rather than using "EV = Bonus - (Wagering Requirement * House Edge)"